# Angular 8 get value from input by have only id

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Is it possible by using angular 8 with typescript to get value from input by know only id of this element?

Comment: `document.getElementById`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simple add this code in your **.ts** file inside the block where you want value of input from id

```
(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("unitPrice")).value;
```

Comment: perfectly working in `ng-version="6.1.10"`

Answer (score 0):

your best bet would be

```
@ViewChild("dataBlock") block: ElementRef;

clearContent() {
  this.block.nativeElement.innerHTML = "";
}
```

as the angular way because in ng app it is never meant to be work in browser

> you can run Angular in a web worker which doesn't have direct access
>   to the DOM

but if you are firm on `id` method then you can definitely use classic javascript methods `document.getElementById`